# Workstation receiving a PXE-E51 when trying to load WDS

Tags: windows, pxe-boot, wds

I have two of the same laptop, Dell Latitude E6320 that I am testing my WDS server with. The first is the one I used to capture the image and then deploy the same image on. The second however gets an error code PXE-E51 which means no DHCP or proxyDHCP offers were received. Keep in mind these are the same exact model and I'm using the same ethernet cable on the same Patch leading to the same switch. What could be causing this issue?

Comment: How big is your DHCP scope and what is the lease time? Also, do you have WDS configured to respond to all clients (known and unknown)?

Comment: Sorry its been a while and the scope is a whole class c subnet lease time is 3 days and WDS is configured to respond to all clients known and unknown

Answer (score 1):

it could be lot of things...
Why do not run Wireshark on the WDS PC and pinpoint the DHCP traffic when you boot the client?
You should see the DHCPDISCOVERY , DHCPOFFER, DHCPREQUEST, DHCPACK. That way you know if the WDS is really receiving the DHCP request and also if it is answering to it...